# Differentiating the four-velocity contracted with itself

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, vectors, differentiation

Let us denote $u^\mu$ as the contravarient component of a four velocity at a point in some coordinate system for a pseudo-Riemannian manifold. I want to examine the following equation.
$$\partial_\nu(u^\mu u_\mu) = 2(\partial_\nu u^\mu)u_\mu  \tag{1}$$
Since we can always find a local Cartesian coordinate system, I can write as the following.
$$\partial_\nu (u^\mu u_\mu) = (\partial_\nu u^\mu) u_\mu + u^\mu (\partial_\nu u_\mu)$$
and since
$$u^\mu (\partial_\nu u_\mu) = u^\mu (\partial_\nu \eta_{\mu \sigma}u^\sigma) = \eta_{\mu \sigma} u^\mu (\partial_\nu u^\sigma) = u_\sigma (\partial_\nu u^\sigma),$$
I have
$$\partial_\nu(u^\mu u_\mu) = 2(\partial_\nu u^\mu)u_\mu \tag{2}$$
as desired, justifying equation 1). However, if I choose different coordinate system, then in general
$$u^\mu (\partial_\nu u_\mu) = u^\mu (\partial_\nu g_{\mu \sigma}u^\sigma) \neq g_{\mu \sigma} u^\mu (\partial_\nu u^\sigma) = u_\sigma (\partial_\nu u^\sigma). \tag{3}$$

However, equation 1) (as justified in local Cartesian coordinates by equation 2)) is a tensorial equation, meaning that it transforms according to tensor transformations under coordinate transformation, hence must be valid in all coordinate systems. This is a contradiction with equation 3).

Can someone shed light on this statement?

Comment: Why do you think (1) is true?

Comment: I think it is true because as shown in equation 2), 1) is true in local Cartesian coordinates, and due to its tensorial nature, it is true in general coordinate systems.

Comment: Oh, should I write $\nabla_\nu (u^\mu u_\mu)$ in general coordinate systems?

Comment: The problem is that the right-hand side of (1) is not a tensor, because $\partial_\nu u^\mu$ isn't.

Comment: Thank you, I got it! Then is $\nabla_\nu (u^\mu u_\mu) = 2 (\nabla_\nu u^\mu) u_\mu $ true, since both sides are tensors?

Comment: Yes you must use the covariant derivative

Comment: Is it true that $\:u^\mu u_\mu=c^2=\:$constant in a frame and invariant between frames ??? So, $\partial_\nu(u^\mu u_\mu)\equiv 0$.